# How to prove this function is not lipschitzianan

Tags: lipschitz-functions

I have this exercise for my subject Differentials Equations II:

---

Let $\emptyset\neq I\subset\mathbb{R}$ an interval and $f:\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a function. Let's denote

$I^*=\{t\in I:\exists f'(t)\}$

Suppose that exists a sequence $t_n\in I^*$ such $|f'(t_n)|\longrightarrow\infty$

Prove that $f$ is not lipschitzian in I.

---

I have tried to prove this by showing that there's a point where $f'$ is not bounded. That point should be the limit of the sequence $t_n$, but I do not know if $t_n$ is convergent. In addition, I do not know if $f$ is continous (I do not know if that's an error from my teacher, because if we are talking about lipschitzian functions it should be at least continous I suppose).

Any hints?

Comment: I assume $I$ is an interval, although you didn't specify that.  Does it have any other properties (e.g., closed? bounded?)

Comment: Sorry for that. No, it does not have any other propreties.

Comment: Then I don't think you can assume your $t_n$ sequence converges.

Comment: well, since Lipschitz implies continuous, if $f$ is not continuous it cannot be Lipschitz

Comment: Then, if $t_n$ does not converge, how should i resolve this? Any hints?